# Цикл и поиск массива

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
var str='test';
var mas1=['a','b']; приставка
var mas2=['c','d']; окончание
mas1[Math.floor(Math.random()*mas1.length)]+''+str+''+mas2[Math.floor(Math.random()*mas2.length)];
```

запустили 2 раза получили

```
var mas3='btestd','atestd'
```

как сделать цикл чтобы он проверял если в массиве 3 уже есть такая строка то подобрать другую и так бесконечно пока не будет 4 слова... (AtestС, AtestD, BtestC, BtestD)

Comment: http://learn.javascript.ru/while-for  
Вам нужно два вложенных цикла.

Answer (score 2):

можно сделать как то так:

```
var str='test';
var mas1=['a','b']; приставка
var mas2=['c','d']; окончание
var mas3 = [];

for (var i1 = 0; i1 < mas1.length; i1++) {
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < mas2.length; i2++) {
        mas3.push(mas1[i1] + str + mas2[i2]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

надеюсь я правильно понял постановку вопроса, и тогда решение выглядит как-то так:

```
var str='test';
var mas1=['a','b'];
var mas2=['c','d'];
var mas3 = [];

while(mas3.length != 4){
  var newStr = mas1[Math.floor(Math.random()*mas1.length)]+str+mas2[Math.floor(Math.random()*mas2.length)];
  if(mas3.indexOf(newStr) === -1){
    mas3.push(newStr);
  }
}
```